# method that splits a 2D array into 4 parts in Java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, math

I'm creating a method that splits a 2D array into 4 parts.

For example if the grid is:

```
1 5 6 2
3 1 6 5
6 3 9 4
3 8 4 2
```

The method should return this:

```
1 5
3 1

6 2
6 5

6 3
3 8

9 4
4 2
```

The code I have only prints the 2D array into a grid. What I was thinking was to create 4 new grids in the method and then, with a series of forloops and if statements, print each new grid. that's why there are 4 2d arrays in the method. Any suggestions?

```
public class problem {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[][] array1 = { {1, 5,   6, 2}, 
                            { 3, 1,    6, 5}, 
                            
                            { 6, 3,    9, 4}, 
                            {3, 8,     4, 2} };
        
        splitGrid(array1);
    }
    
    public static void splitGrid( double[][] grid ) {
        //Create four new grids here
        double[][] TopLeft;
        double[][] TopRight;
        double[][] BottomLeft;
        double[][] BottonRight;
        // Filling the top-left grid
        for( int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
            System.out.println();
            for(int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(grid[i][j] + " " );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should your solution only work with 4x4 grids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, one of them (and probably the safest!) of course being `copy` methods from the standard lib's `Arrays` class. However, if you are looking to develop your "manual" algorithmic skills with this one, then something like the following could be appropriate:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[][] fourByFourArray = {{1, 5, 6, 2},
            {3, 1, 6, 5},
            {6, 3, 9, 4},
            {3, 8, 4, 2}};
    System.out.println("Printing 4x4 array: ");
    splitGridInto4equalParts(fourByFourArray);
    System.out.println("Printing 6x6 array: ");
    double[][] sixBySixArray = {{1, 5, 7, 6, 8, 2},
            {3, 1, 9, 6, 1, 5},
            {6, 3, 20, 10, 2, 4},
            {3, 8, 31, 2, 5, 2},
            {3, 1, 9, 6, 1, 5},
            {3, 8, 31, 2, 5, 2},
    };
    splitGridInto4equalParts(sixBySixArray);
}

public static void splitGridInto4equalParts(double[][] grid) {
    //assuming grid has equal sides
    var gridSide = grid.length;
    //assuming grid side is even number
    var half = gridSide / 2;
    //filling arrays
    double[][] topLeft = getPart(grid, half, 0, 0, half, half);
    double[][] topRight = getPart(grid, half, 0, half, half, gridSide);
    double[][] bottomLeft = getPart(grid, half, half, 0, gridSide, half);
    double[][] bottomRight = getPart(grid, half, half, half, gridSide, gridSide);
    //printing
    printGridPart(half, topLeft);
    printGridPart(half, topRight);
    printGridPart(half, bottomLeft);
    printGridPart(half, bottomRight);
}

private static double[][] getPart(double[][] grid, int partSideLength, int gridRow, int gridCol, int gridRowLimit, int gridColLimit) {
    double[][] gridPart = new double[partSideLength][partSideLength];
    int resRow = 0, resCol = 0;
    //saving original grid column parameter, in order to reset it when execution moves on new grid row
    int origGridCol = gridCol;
    while (gridRow < gridRowLimit) {
        while (gridCol < gridColLimit) {
            gridPart[resRow][resCol] = grid[gridRow][gridCol];
            //checking whether result column has reached limit in order to move to next row and reset column
            if (resCol == partSideLength - 1) {
                resRow++;
                resCol = 0;
                break;
            }
            //moving one column to the right for both result and grid
            resCol++;
            gridCol++;
        }
        //checking whether result row has reached limit, if so exit from traversing rows
        if (resRow == partSideLength) {
            break;
        }
        gridCol = origGridCol;
        gridRow++;
    }
    return gridPart;
}


private static void printGridPart(int gridLength, double[][] gridPart) {
    for (int i = 0; i < gridLength; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < gridLength; j++) {
            System.out.print(gridPart[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

This outputs:

```
Printing 4x4 array: 
1.0 5.0 
3.0 1.0 

6.0 2.0 
6.0 5.0 

6.0 3.0 
3.0 8.0 

9.0 4.0 
4.0 2.0 

Printing 6x6 array: 
1.0 5.0 7.0 
3.0 1.0 9.0 
6.0 3.0 20.0 

6.0 8.0 2.0 
6.0 1.0 5.0 
10.0 2.0 4.0 

3.0 8.0 31.0 
3.0 1.0 9.0 
3.0 8.0 31.0 

2.0 5.0 2.0 
6.0 1.0 5.0 
2.0 5.0 2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return an array of grid that contains `{topLeft, topRight, bottomLeft, bottomRight}` like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[][] array1 = {
        {1, 5, 6, 2},
        {3, 1, 6, 5},
        {6, 3, 9, 4},
        {3, 8, 4, 2}};

    double[][][] result = splitGrid(array1);

    for (double[][] grid : result) {
        for (double[] row : grid)
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static double[][][] splitGrid(double[][] grid) {
    int rows = grid.length, cols = grid[0].length;
    int subRows = rows / 2, subCols = cols / 2;
    double[][][] result = {
        new double[subRows][], new double[subRows][],
        new double[rows - subRows][], new double[rows - subRows][]};
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        if (i < subRows) {
            result[0][i] = Arrays.copyOf(grid[i], subCols);
            result[1][i] = Arrays.copyOfRange(grid[i], subCols, cols);
        } else {
            result[2][i - subRows] = Arrays.copyOf(grid[i], subCols);
            result[3][i - subRows] = Arrays.copyOfRange(grid[i], subCols, cols);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

output:

```
[1.0, 5.0]
[3.0, 1.0]

[6.0, 2.0]
[6.0, 5.0]

[6.0, 3.0]
[3.0, 8.0]

[9.0, 4.0]
[4.0, 2.0]
```